# Crypto++ exception calling messageEnd

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I use following code to decrypt a file:

```
FileSource fe(fileUrl.c_str(), false,
                  new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(decryptor, new FileSink(
                          std::string(fileUrl).c_str()), CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |  CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END ));

        size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 16384;
    while (remaining && !fe.SourceExhausted()) {
        const unsigned int req = STDMIN(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
        fe.Pump(req);
        fe.Flush(false);

        remaining -= req;
    }
    fe.MessageEnd();
```

If i try to do this without the fe.MessageEnd(), my decrypted File is 16 bytes short. So i thought i need to call MessageEnd() to fix this problem.
But if i call MessageEnd() i get Follwing Exception: BufferedTransformation: this object doesn't allow input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i call MessageEnd() I get Follwing Exception: ***`BufferedTransformation: this object doesn't allow input`***...

Correct. The `FileSource` is a source, and the message must exist. You can't call `Put` or `Put2` on the source to add additional data to the message.

---

I think you have two options to take more control over the signals.

***First***

Call `Flush` on the `Source`.

```c++
const int opts = AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |
    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END;

FileSource fe(fileUrl.c_str(), false,
    new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(decryptor, new FileSink(
        std::string(fileUrl).c_str()), opts));

fe.Flush(true);
```

Also see the comments for `Flush` at [Filter::Flush](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_filter.html#ad845deb5113d2bd04d109c05abfd3098) in the manual.

***Second***

Stash a pointer to the filter and call `MessageEnd` on it.

```c++
const int opts = AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |
     AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END;
AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter* adf = NULL;

FileSource fe(fileUrl.c_str(), false,
    adf = new AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter(decryptor, new FileSink(
        std::string(fileUrl).c_str()), opts));
adf.MessageEnd();
```

This is kind of unusual, so I'm not sure what side effects you will encounter.

Don't delete the pointer. The `FileSource` will delete it when it goes out of scope at the closing brace.

---

> ... my decrypted file is 16 bytes short...

In my opinion, this is the problem you should pursue if calling `Flush` on the `Source` does not work for you.

Also keep in mind... The output of ***`AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter`*** is the 2-tuple ***`{ciphertext,mac}`***, so you get ciphertext expansion of 16-bytes because of the MAC. Later, when you use ***`AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter`***, the mac is removed after verifying it. So the recovered text should be the same size as the plain text, both of which should be 16-bytes less than the cipher text.

The thing I am not clear about is, are things working as expected but you don't realize that's how its supposed to work. Or are you really loosing 16-bytes of recovered text somewhere.

Comment: I am loosing 16 bytes of the cleartext in the End. I will look into your options later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your first option using fe.Flush(true) seems to work fine.